# Getting screenshot from a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` that contains a lot of sub `LinearLayouts` which contain `TextViews`. I want to get a screenshot from the parent `LinearLayout` to get a full view of my "Receipt". So I tried to do that:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.llReceipt);
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
```

the problem is the Bitmap b get a `null` value.

Is there any solution to solve it?

Comment: can u post your layout

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your bitmap is null but I've used this bit before to get a screen shot of a custom view and it worked:

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (view==mainPage.boardView) { 
        canvas.drawColor(BoardView.BOARD_BG_COLOR);
    } else if (bgDrawable!=null) { 
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    } else { 
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    view.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    view.layout(0, 0, width, height); 
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492354/create-bitmap-from-view-makes-view-disappear-how-to-get-view-canvas)!

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem:
I called the `getScreenShot()` Function from the `onCreate()` Function which doesn't work.
it should call it after this step.